# gdata internal error

Tags: python, gdata, google-sites

Since yesterday a working Python gdata program has stopped working after I changed the IP address used.
I receive the following stack trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\prod\googleSite\googleSite2.py", line 23, in 
>       feed = client.GetContentFeed()
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\sites\client.py", line 155, in get_c
>   ontent_feed
>       auth_token=auth_token, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\client.py", line 635, in get_feed
>       **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\client.py", line 320, in request
>       RequestError)
>   gdata.client.RequestError: Server responded with: 500, Internal Error

The code is as follow:

```
    import gdata.sites.client
import gdata.sites.data
client = gdata.sites.client.SitesClient(source='xxx', site='yyy')
client.ssl = True  # Force API requests through HTTPS
client.ClientLogin('user@googlemail.com', 'password', client.source);
feed = client.GetContentFeed();
```

Update:
The issue fixes itself after an hour - is there any kind of commit or logout to avoid this?

Comment: Are you passing credentials to google in order to get your auth token or was the google account previously set up to automatically allow auths from a certain IP?

Comment: I have changed the question accordingly.

Comment: I have created a issue on google's issue system and I am now working around this by continously trying at the startup and keeping my own list afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not passing anything in `GetContentFeed`, it's using `CONTENT_FEED_TEMPLATE % (self.domain, self.site)` as the URI. I'm not sure if the IP change had an impact on what the self.domain/self.site values should be, but it might be worth checking those out.

Comment: I really don't know a ton about this python API, but I believe they are defined in client.py, though their value could be saved anywhere in your program. I am not sure what they SHOULD be, but it's a starting point that you can look into. Sorry that I can't be of more assistance.